# Rooks on a Chessboard

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion, chessboard

> $8$ rooks are randomly placed on different squares of a chessboard. A rook is said to attack all of the squares in its row and its column.
>
> Compute the probability that every square is occupied or attacked by at least $1$ rook. You may leave unevaluated binomial coefficients in your answer.

I divided the question into cases, where Case $1$ is when there're only one rook in every row and column (which can be done in $8!$ ways).

But then, when I get to Case $2$ (which is when there're $2$ rooks in every row **or** column) I'm stuck. There're $\dbinom{8}{2}$ choices for choosing the squares in which the rooks will be, $8\cdot 7$ choices for those two rooks ... then 8C2 again for the next row, but then I overlap having more than one rook in a column ... and it's all confusing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using in [inclusion-exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).  Count the ways they fill all the rows, add the ways they fill all the columns, and subtract the ways they fill both because you counted them twice.

Comment: Yes. I agree with this. Though, to be pedantic, it would be a good idea to show that the *only* way to fulfil the condition in the question is if either all $8$ rows or all $8$ columns (or both) each contain a rook.